# Cygwin: Mapping a directory

Tags: linux, cygwin

I want to map a directory `c:\Animal\Cat` to `/Cat`
So that when i use Cygwin, and just type `cd /Cat` from any directory, it goes to `/c/Animal/Cat`
How would i do that?

I have already done `mount -c /`, so i have the following when i do the df command:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks Used      Available  Use% Mounted on  
C:/cygwin/bin  488384532 187949036 300435496  39% /usr/bin  
C:/cygwin/lib  488384532 187949036 300435496  39% /usr/lib  
C:/cygwin      488384532 187949036 300435496  39% /  
C:             488384532 187949036 300435496  39% /c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you'd prefer to tackle this, here are two suggestions:

- You can create a symbolic link for this directory:

  `ln -s /source/directory/ /Cat`

  You can test this by then running `ls /Cat`
- You can create an alias to simply move to the directory using a
  friendly name:

  `cat >>.bashrc`
     `# Alias for changing to a desired directory`
     `alias Dog='cd /source/directory'`

Then issues the command `source ~/.bashrc` or log out and back in. Then, issuing the new `Dog` alias will `cd` to your desired directory.

It may be best to steer clear of aliasing system commands when using friendly names in your .bashrc that are close to them (Replace [cat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) with Dog for instance).